# update-initramfs: failed

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg

Recently I restored accidentally deleted `/share` folder of `Ubuntu-21.04` by copying it from a  live `Ubuntu-21.04`, and somehow managed to start the computer. Since then Computer is working fine, but following is the issue:

**Part-1**

My computer (`Ubuntu-21.04`) boots only in kernal `5.11.0-25`, out of three kernels `5.11.0-37`, `5.11.0-34`, and `5.11.0-25`.

Boot gets stuck in Kernels (`*37*, *34*`), gives the error:

`end kernel panic -not sync: vfs : unable to mount root fs on unknown block [0 0]`

**Part-2**

If I boot in the kernel `5.11.0-25`, then problem is that I am unable to install any packages, or upgrade the ubunutu. It gives following set of errors for any installation or upgradation.

**Output of `sudo apt update`**

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates    InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 110 kB in 1s (146 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

**Output of `sudo apt upgrade`:**

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree... Done
 Reading state information... Done
 Calculating upgrade... Done
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.139ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic (5.11.0-37.41) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.139ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
Error: /sbin/zdb is not executable.
Error: /sbin/zpool is not executable.
Error: /sbin/zfs is not executable.
Error: /sbin/mount.zfs is not executable.
Error: /lib/udev/vdev_id is not executable.
Error: /lib/udev/zvol_id is not executable.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zfs failed with return 2.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic    with 2.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script    subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic    (5.11.0-37.41) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic
Error: /sbin/zdb is not executable.
Error: /sbin/zpool is not executable.
Error: /sbin/zfs is not executable.
Error: /sbin/mount.zfs is not executable.
Error: /lib/udev/vdev_id is not executable.
Error: /lib/udev/zvol_id is not executable.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zfs failed with return 2.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-37-generic    with 2.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with    return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic    (--configure):
installed linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic package post-installation    script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
 Errors were encountered while processing:
initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**File system**

`/dev/sdb2      ext4    19G   16G  1.6G  92% /`

`/dev/sdb1      vfat   380M  6.9M  373M   2% /boot/efi`

Comment: @Nmath, Ubuntu version is mentioned on top of post. I have mentioned that I get the same set of errors while installing any package or upgrading.

Comment: @Nmath Updated Question for more clarity

Comment: @Nmath. I have answerd your all three question in post. Request you to see the post again

Comment: Based on this info I think you might need a clean install.  A lot of files needed by the system and software would have been under `/usr/share` which I think you are referring to as the directory you accidentally deleted. Although it was a good idea to try to copy the files from another installation, those files wouldn't exactly replace what existed on your installed system, assuming you've made updates, added/removed software. Your mistake may have been fatal and you might need to perform a clean installation in order to get your system fully functional again.

Comment: @Nmath Clean installation will be very time consuming as I will have to install all the packages again for my use. Do You think of any other alternate ?

Comment: The two packages that are "not fully installed or removed" appear to be `initramfs-tools` and `linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic`.  Maybe you could try to `sudo apt purge` those packages and reinstall them, but I'm not certain it would fix the problem and might cause other issues. Definitely make sure your backups are in a good place

Comment: OK, I will try, thanks